# MySQL, is there any way to use multiple alias?

Tags: mysql

Given we have a database with the tables:
"artist" (columns: name, id) and
"song" (title, composers_id, songwriters_id).

I want to print the songs with the composers name and songwriters name.
I have succeeded in printing the composers name only with:

```
SELECT title, name AS Composers_Name 
  FROM artist, song 
    WHERE song.composers_id = artist.id;
```

I am failing to fetch the songwriters name..
What I tried was this:

```
SELECT title, name AS Composers_Name, name AS Songwriters_name
  FROM artist, song 
    WHERE song.composers_id = artist.id AND song.songwriters_id = artist.id;
```

But this returns all the songs that the composers and songwriter is the same person.
I am thinking of using JOIN but I'm not sure how..

Comment: Your question is really unclear. You only have one `name` column (in the `artist` table). How can you use it as both the composer's name and the songwriter's name?

Comment: What's unclear about it? Suppose the artist is a composer or a songwriter.

Comment: Chris, great. How do you know which is which (which one should be the songwriter and which the composer)? Are you now asking about combining multiple rows into a single row? If so, you need a way to differentiate the type the name represents.

Comment: I know that I am late to comment and answer on this, but you can try a concept called relational division in SQL that would actually clear your problem. I recently faced a similar issue and tackled it using relational division on the table. Furthermore, using this way, you also donot need to perform a join, and a single query is required only.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to select from the table artist 2 times.

```
select s.title, a1.name AS Composer, a2.name as songwriter
from song s, artist a1, artist a2 
where s.composers_id = a1.id and s.songwriters_id = a2.id;
```

assuming that Composers and Songwriters are both stored in the table artist.

Comment: That's what I was trying to do, but I didn't know that I had to rewrite a table to re-alias it.

Answer (score 2):

Use left join

```
SELECT s.title, c.name AS Composers_Name, a.name AS Songwriters_name
  FROM song s
  LEFT JOIN artist a ON s.songwriters_id = a.artistID
  LEFT JOIN artist c ON s.composers_id = c.artistID
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to go with join OR defined each table alias to access their fields.

```
SELECT a.title, a.name AS Composers_Name, s.name AS Songwriters_name
FROM artist a, song s
```

But in your question songwriter name field is missing. Between you can follow this way to access it.